# What is an appropriate URI for a user registration form in a RESTful setting?

Tags: rest, laravel, uri

I'm working on a web application under Laravel and I'm trying to be as RESTful as I can, but admittedly this is the first time writing this kind of application.

I'm specifically trying to create RESTful URI's for the controllers of my project.

So far I have (in pseudo code)...

```
URI                 Goes to...      Desc
---                 ----------      ----
/ GET
    if logged in    dashboard GET
    else            frontpage GET

login GET           login GET       login form
login POST          login POST      attempt login
login DELETE        login DELETE    logout

user GET
    if logged in    user GET        show user control panel
    else            login GET       redirect to the login w/ error
```

So far so good, but how should I go about creating a new user?

I had a couple of ideas, for example:

```
URI                 Goes to...      Desc
---                 ----------      ----
user/create GET     register GET    show the create user form
user/create POST    register POST   attempt to create a new user
```

So we use a `register` controller here, but we hide it behind the user URI.

Advantage here is that we stick to HTTP actions (just GET and POST), and we create a nice readable URI.

Disadvantage is that our URI does not accurately represent our controller.

```
URI                 Goes to...      Desc
---                 ----------      ----
register GET        register GET    show the create user form
register POST       register POST   attempt to create a new user
```

In this case we have A. used HTTP controls, B. created a URI that is a representation of our controller, and C. created a nice readable URI, but unfortunately our URI isn't really representational of the data. In no way is this `register` controller representative of our user.

Which is more appropriate? Why? Is there a better way? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In those cases I would create a Route::resource for users, like so:

```
Route::resource('user', 'UsersController');
```

and to optimize user readability add:

```
Route::get('/signup', 'UsersController@create');
```

For logins I would create a Route::resource for sessions, like so:

```
Route::resource('sessions', 'SessionsController');
```

and to again, optimize user readability add:

```
Route::get('/login', 'SessionsController@create');
```

Using resources makes some methods ready for you, but you are not using all of them.
So you might want to reduce that to the ones you use, only. Like so:

```
Route::resource('sessions', 'SessionsController', ['only' => ['create', 'store', 'destroy']);
```

Hope this helps you further.

Comment: Yes this is great, thanks a lot. I'd like to use named routes, which is causing me some troubles with the SessionController in this format. I want the user to see /login/ all the time, never /session/, so I'm wondering if it would be appropriate to do the following: 

Route::resource('/login', 'SessionController', ['only' => ['create', 'store', 'destroy'], 'as'  => 'login']);

Comment: If you do that /login will call the index() method on the SessionsController. What I did is simply creating an alias (/logins) for /sessions/create. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: Yeah I do. How about this?

Route::get('/login',   'SessionController@create');

Route::resource('/login', 'SessionController', [
 'only' => ['create', 'store', 'destroy'],
 'as'  => 'login'
]);

Comment: Now you're linking login to the controller method and then overwriting it and linking it to the sessionscontroller. Just do it as I did above. The user wont even see session/create etc.

Answer (score 1):

In your case I will go for the user readability. I always prefer to have something like `example.com/signup`, `example.com/register` to show the form that handles the creation of the user. As a user, the URL tells me that I'm in the right place, even if the controller that handles this is totally different. The middle URL (where you will post your data) is not important because it will not displayed to your users: you will redirect them to the create form or the success page.

If you were building an API (the intended users are developers) I will go for a `POST users`, because developers should be familiar with REST principles.